# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.74 TiB for an array with shape (287318, 3704243) and data type float64

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, tokenize

I am working on a matrix `tfidf_matrix` of shape (287318, 3704243) which i am trying to reuse for later computation. Here is my full code

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()                                    
# text shape is (287318,)
tfidf_matrix  = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
X = tfidf_matrix.todense()  # error here

pca_num_components = 2
reduced_data = PCA(n_components=pca_num_components).fit_transform(X)
```

I am trying to reduce that `tfidf_matrix` by PCA for plotting purpose but i get a memory error issue at line  `X = tfidf_matrix.todense()` saying

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.74 TiB for an array with shape (287318, 3704243) and data type float64
```

Is there any way to solve the problem please?

Comment: That's a huge volume of data... you're probably going to have to find a way to process your data in chunks.

Comment: thank you, this is indeed the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (although not perfect) is to randomly pick a specific number of rows and perform PCA on it as follows.

```
max_items = np.random.choice(range(tfidf_matrix.shape[0]), size=3000, replace=False)
X=tfidf_matrix[max_items,:].todense()   
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)
```

We can change the `size` parameter if needed